# Convert IDictionary<T, Task<bool>> to IObservable<KeyValuePair<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I have a function to replace a single entity in a repository (e.g. a database) with another entity. This returns a Task, the result of which indicates if a replacement was successful.

```
// Single Replace
Task<bool> Replace(Entity e, Entity Other);
```

Now say I want to create the same function, but allowing to replace several entities. My idea for a function signature was:

```
// Multiple Replace
IObservable<KeyValuePair<Entity, bool>> Replace(IDictionary<Entity, Entity> Map);
```

Map contains a dictionary whose keys are the entities which shall be replaced, and its values are the new entities that shall replace the old ones.

Each KeyValuePair of this Map dictionary should return a KeyValuePair< Entity, bool >, where the key corresponds to Map.Key (= the Entitiy which shall be replaced), and Value is a bool that indicates whether the replacement was successful or not.

I'd like to return this as a stream, hence I chose IObservable< KeyValuePair< Entity,bool > >, pushing out a KeyValuePair< Entity,bool > for each result that becomes available.

For now, I'd just like to have the "Multiple Replace" function use the "Single Replace" function to convert; but how can I make these calls and return the result in the required format?

```
Task<bool> Replace(Entity e, Entity Other)
{
  // ... do the work ...
}

IObservable<KeyValuePair<Entity, bool>> Replace(IDictionary<Entity, Entity> Map)
{
  // How this should work:
  // for each KeyValuePair in Map, call the Single Replace function
  // and - once available - return its result (bool) mapped to the Entity in the
  // resulting Observable stream

  IDictionary<Entity, Task<bool>> dict = Map.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => Replace(x.Key, x.Value));

  // .. now what? How can I now convert the dict into an IObservable<KeyValuePair<Entity,bool>> ?

}
```

Would appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on Peter's solution, a little modification that leverages Task.ToObservable:

```
    IObservable<Tuple<Entity, bool>> Replace(IDictionary<Entity, Entity> Map)
    {
        Task<Tuple<Entity, bool>>[] tasks = new Task<Tuple<Entity, bool>>(Map.Count);
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var kvp in Map)
        {
            tasks[i++] = ReplaceAsync(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

        return tasks
            .Select(x => x.ToObservable())
            .Merge();   // or use .Concat for sequential execution
    }
```

Seems to work fine, does anyone spot any potential issues?

Using .Merge gives an IObservable that starts the tasks in parallel, providing results as they finish, and completes when all tasks are done.

Alternatively I can use .Concat() to execute them sequentially, i.e. start the first task first, wait for it to finish, then start the second task, etc.

Nice thing is that error handling comes for free I believe, so whenever any of the tasks throws an Exception, OnError of the IObservable is auomatically called.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with the Reactive extensions -- indeed, I wasn't even aware of the `ToObservable()` and `Merge()` methods, which do seem to simplify the scenario quite a lot. My only concern might be that the above creates a sequence of observables, rather than an observable on a sequence; the latter _might_ be _slightly_ more efficient. But IMHO, code clarity is much more important so you would need to prove a genuine and significant performance issue before worrying about that.

Comment: In any case, my example necessarily leaves out niceties like error-handling, which just further undermines any motivation to use that instead of the built-in operators. Glad that the main point of my answer got you where you needed to go. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows what you're doing, and especially how you intend to implement the `IObservable<T>` object returned from your method, it's impossible to offer specific advice. However, I can provide some suggestions that should at least point you in a useful direction.

First, I will suggest that it is more useful to have a `Task<Tuple<Entity, bool>>` (or `Task<KeyValuePair<Entity, bool>>`, though I am not very fond of using dictionary-related types for non-dictionary-dependent code…i.e. where you're really just pairing things rather than having a true key/value pairing). That way, when the task completes, you know from the task itself all of the information you need.

This can be accomplished with a simple helper method, e.g.:

```
async Task<Tuple<Entity, bool>> ReplaceAsync(Entity e, Entity other)
{
    return Tuple.Create(e, await Replace(e, other));
}
```

I used `Tuple` here, but of course you may create a named type for the purpose, and doing so may in fact help readability of the code.

Having done that, you can then just enumerate all of the items in your input dictionary (or other more appropriate collection :) ), and then use `Task.WhenAny()` to iteratively remove and publish each completed item as they occur:

```
IObservable<Tuple<Entity, bool>> Replace(IDictionary<Entity, Entity> Map)
{
    Task<Tuple<Entity, bool>>[] tasks = new Task<Tuple<Entity, bool>>(Map.Count);
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var kvp in Map)
    {
        tasks[i++] = ReplaceAsync(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    // Create the IObservable object somehow. Make sure it has the
    // array of tasks in it. E.g. (see below for TaskObservable example)

    TaskObservable<Tuple<Entity, bool>> observable =
        new TaskObservable<Tuple<Entity, bool>>(tasks);

    // Now, start running the observable object. Note: not really all that great
    // to ignore the returned Task object but without more context in your question
    // I can't offer anything more specific. You will probably want to store the
    // Task object *somewhere*, await it, wrap all that in try/catch, etc. to
    // make sure you are correctly monitoring the progress of the task.
    var _ = observable.Run();

    return observable;
}
```

The `IObservable<T>` might look something like:

```
class TaskObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private class ObserverItem : IDisposable
    {
        public readonly IObserver<T> Observer;
        public readonly TaskObservable<T> Owner;

        public ObserverItem(IObserver<T> observer, TaskObservable<T> owner)
        {
            Observer = observer;
            Owner = owner;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!Owner._observerItems.Contains(this))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "This observer is no longer subscribed");
            }

            Owner._observerItems.Remove(this);
        }
    }

    private readonly Task<T>[] _tasks;
    private readonly List<ObserverItem> _observerItems = new List<ObserverItem>();

    public TaskObservable(Task<T>[] tasks)
    {
        _tasks = tasks;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        ObserverItem item = new ObserverItem(observer, this);

        _observerItems.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    private void Publish(T t)
    {
        foreach (ObserverItem item in _observerItems)
        {
            item.Observer.OnNext(t);
        }
    }

    private void Complete()
    {
        foreach (ObserverItem item in _observerItems)
        {
            item.Observer.OnCompleted();
        }
    }

    async Task Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            Task<T> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

            Publish(completedTask.Result);
        }

        Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your well thought through answer Peter, this is very helpful and interesting to read - I learned quite a bit from your TaskObservable class. And I think transforming to Task< KeyValuePair< Entity, bool > > was indeed a key point - I think that way I can even avoid a class such as TaskObservable altogether, while having convenient error handling. Will post below, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've missed anything, but I think this might work for you:

```
public IObservable<KeyValuePair<T, bool>> Convert<T>(IDictionary<T, Task<bool>> source)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<KeyValuePair<T, bool>>(o =>
                (
                    from s in source.ToObservable()
                    from v in s.Value.ToObservable()
                    select new KeyValuePair<T, bool>(s.Key, v)
                ).Subscribe(o));
}
```